# Cognos session parameters usage

Tags: session, parameters, frameworks, ldap, cognos

I have setup LDAP authentication and set up "custom properties" in cognos configuration to get a attribute i have defined in the LDAP entry.

For example this custom property is called ORG_NAME, how do i use this ORG_NAME in report studio as a parameter to filter on?  I have seen online about mapping with Framework manager.. however the particular reports i am using access the database directly and DO NOT have a framework manager package associated with them, so i need to use the ORG_NAME without using FM....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same syntax you would use in FM.  So, for example:

```
#sq($account.personalInfo.givenName)#
```

will return the first name, and so on.

If you feel some burning need to for user-written SQL, instead of using FM, you can include the macro as a query item in your "outer" query (that gets the results from your sql query, Query2 in the image below).

[image]